# How to log events from Raspberry Pi running on Windows 10 IoT to HDFS using Flume

Tags: hadoop, raspberry-pi, hdfs, flume, windows-10-iot-core

I want to log my LED blinking (On/OFF) and different room temperature to HDFS. I found this http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html.

It says "Flume currently supports Avro, log4j, syslog, and Http POST (with a JSON body) as ways to transfer data from a external source".

My question here is what should I use if I want to log my Raspberry Pi generated data to HDFS. Please provide me some tutorial link or guide me. OR Please let me know the best way to do this? Hope I have asked my question simple.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - I am not familiar with Flume.
Just reading your statement about what Flume supports for logging I think your only option is HTTP POST with JSON. I say this because:
log4j is a Java logging utility. There is a .Net version of this but I a) don't know if it will run in a universal app and b) likely does not have an extension to support Flume logging. 
syslog is a Linux logging mechanism that does not exist on Win IoT
Avro I am not at all familiar with but likely does not have a Win IoT version.

That leaves you with HTTP POST. .Net on Win IoT has classes that will allow you to accomplish this reasonably easily. Take a look at Windows.Web.HttpClient class's postAsync method. I've not tried it personally.

Mark Radbourne [MSFT]

Comment: Could you please show me a road map, how to do it? considering my problem...Any helpful link?